# Trigger a function when an excel file in my Google Drive is overwritten

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, triggers

I have an excel xlsm on my computer that is updated every morning and overwrites another workbook with the same title on the google drive folder, uploading it to Google Drive itself. I have to work with a specific Google Spreadsheet that pulls data from this excel file, so is there a way to run a function automatically (with Goggle App script) when the xlsm is updated (and the old file is overwritten)?

Comment: You could write such a function.  If I wanted to do it, I would do it with Java and a Google Apps Script web app or possibly one of the rest API's.   The Java program would reside on your computer and take data from your Excel Spreadsheet and send it via a webapp or an API connection to the a Google spreadsheet.  But Google Apps Script runs on the Google Server and has no direct access to your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would implement something like this, I would try using installable time-driven trigger and check last update with `DriveApp.getFileById('your-id').getLastUpdated(); //if your id doesn't change`, using a short interval, like 5 mins. You can create time-driven triggers in https://script.google.com/home/triggers

With your GAS project open, you can go straight to your project triggers, by clicking the "clock" button. (Current project triggers)

[Trigger button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfVir.png)

Comment: The file the OP wants to check is on his computer.  As OP said `I have an excel xlsm on my computer`

Comment: I could understand that he is using Google Drive on desktop and keeping sync on. If it needs to be uploaded, my answer is incorrect.

Comment: You may be right I read it again and the implication is that a file in his google drive folder is getting the update.  So polling is possibly a solution.

Comment: @BrunoPolo I admit I'm new to GAS, any ideas of how to install such a trigger?

Comment: @Ken just edited my answer, please check if you're able to do it.

Comment: @BrunoPolo Thank you very much!